# Error: setBackgroundColorTransparent() not a function in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Apps Script to change the background colors of certain rows of cells in a Google Sheet. For some reason, when I run them as a function of a range of cells (not that I have tried otherwise), setBackgroundColor('white') works, while setBackgroundColorTransparent() invokes a "TypeError: not a function" message. Am I missing some bit with the usage or syntax of setBackgroundColorTransparent()?

My code:

```
function colorSundays() {
  var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
    var currentCell = sheet.getRange(i, 1);
    var value = currentCell.getValues();
    if (value == 'Sunday') {
      var currentRow = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, maxColumns);
      currentRow.setBackgroundColor('#F87CF8');
    } else {
      var currentRow = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, maxColumns);
//      currentRow.setBackgroundColor('white');
      currentRow.setBackgroundColorTransparent(); // Preferred, but now working right now.
    }
  }
}
```

The error message:

```
[20-06-08 19:09:04:246 CDT] TypeError: currentRow.setBackgroundColorTransparent is not a function
    at colorSundays(Code:52:18)
    at setThisMonth(Code:61:3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- In order to set the backgound color to the default, you tried to use `setBackgroundColorTransparent()`.
- You want to set the background color of cell.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, the method of `setBackgroundColorTransparent()` is not included in the Spreadsheet service. I think that the reason of your issue is this. I thought that in your case, the method of `setBackgroundColorTransparent()` of Class TextStyle in Slides Service might be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style?hl=ru#setbackgroundcolortransparent)
- the method of `setBackgroundColor` is not included in Class Range. In this case, please use `setBackground`.

So when you want to set the background color to the default, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
currentRow.setBackgroundColor('#F87CF8');
```

#### To:

```
currentRow.setBackground('#F87CF8');
```

and

#### From:

```
currentRow.setBackgroundColorTransparent();
```

#### To:

```
currentRow.setBackground(null);
```

#### Note:

- The method of `setBackgroundColor` is not included in Class Range. But from OP's replying, it was found that this method can be used.

#### Reference:

- [setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)

Comment: Weirdly, setBackgroundColor seems to work just as well as setBackground, but yeah, "null" solved my problem. Thanks immensely!

Comment: @themadpsychologist Thank you for replying. When I saw the official document of Class Range, I couldn't find the method of `setBackgroundColor`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) So I recommended to use `setBackground`. But now, when I tested this, I could notice that `setBackgroundColor` works. I'm glad for the information. Thank you so much. For this, I updated my answer.